# Debian Wheezy - VM with GUI on a Host without GUI - Possible?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, gui

Are there any solutions to have a textmode debian wheezy install wherein I can start a virtual machine, which has a GUI installed that will display on one of the screens?

Answer (score 3):

No, not really but please note that the whole distinction between "text mode Debian" and "GUI Debian" exists only in your head ;-)

The idea is that *typically* you either need "a server", and then this typically mean "text mode", or "a workstation" and then this usually means some desktop environment, like GNOME or KDE or XFCE or whatever.  The catch here is that *virtual packages* installing corresponding "desktops" typically depend on one or another package providing the so-called display manager — a program which starts at boot, spawns an X server (a complicated piece of software actually providing a GUI console), runs a login manager on it, and once you manage to successfully log in, it's responsible for setting up a session for you.  Once you quit the session, the display manager kicks in again so you're back at square 0.

But nothing requires you to have a display manager installed (or run at boot).  Just install the [`xorg`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xorg) package and you'll get an X server you're able to run by hand.

Now let's move to a more hardcore stuff.

First, you need to start an X server and then you need to run your GUI program in a way it knows how to contact the spawned X server.

Let's postpone the question of starting an instance of the X server for a moment and talk about how an X-enabled program finds the server.  There's more than one way to do that but the most common one is to look up an environment variable named "DISPLAY" which is supposed to contain the name of the *socket* an instance of the X server listens on for client connection, and the so-called display number.
I don't want to write too much on this here: the crucial bit to understand is that once the X server runs, programs which want to use it typically have to see an appropriately set env. variable to be able to find the server.

And this is where the concept of an "X session" comes into the scene: while you're able to run an instance of X server by hand, it's simpler to use a special program to do that for you, and in addition to run a program or a set of program in a specially cooked environment so that they're able to find the started server.

In the good old days of manually starting X servers and sessions attached to them, people typically used the `startx` script which is still supported and is a part of the [`xinit`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xinit) package.  It spawns an X server and either runs a specified program or executes the `~/.xinitrc` shell script.  You get the idea.

But these days it might be more convenient to use a display manager with autologin — so that you have a ready-made X session sitting on a specified VT right at boot.  Use the [`nodm`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/nodm) package for this.  It autostarts the X server, and then runs the specified script on behalf of the specified user.

In either case, just make sure your VM runs as a part of the X session startup process, or make the VM software see a proper `DISPLAY` environment variable.

**Update on 2016-09-20** to answer the `@LauriK`'s comment:

…Not quite.
Let me explain.
In my answer I've explained how X clients find the X server.
In the X Windows System paradigm, X clients (GUI programs) do not draw anything by themselves but rather channel requests to do it to the instance of an X server they're connected to—via a socket. So the graphical screen (with the mouse pointer) you see on a local machine you're sitting at (that is, on your monitor) is presented to you by an instance of the X server running locally.

Now an interesting property of the X client and the X server being connected
over a socket is that they may actually be running
on different computers—if this socket is networked (say, provided by
the TCP/IP stack).
This is a somewhat lesser-known property of the X Window System,
which is called *the network transparency.*

The crucial bit of the X's network transparency is that the X server
always runs on a local machine (that one which has the monitor and the
input devices connected to it) while the X clients drawing on it
may be run either locally or on any number of remote machines.

This paradigm was born naturally because it was invented in the "mainframe
era": basically, on premises of a typical enterprise / lab / whatever,
there would exist a single costly powerful mainframe and a couple of
way less powerful workstations which,—being less powerful,—would
be equipped with graphical screens.  In such setups, the workstations
would run their X programs on the mainframe, and these programs would draw
on the X servers running on the workstations.

To make it maybe more clear, the X protocol supports a set of primitives
to draw (such as lines, rectangles, filling areas with a certain color etc).

The NX suite (what `nomachine.com` provides) sort of "reverses" the approach
making the whole thing work quite like the RDP (Terminal Server access)
protocol of Windows or VNC.

In this paradigm, both the X clients and the X server they draw via
are all located on a remote machine ("the server") but instead of drawing
on an actual hardware screen (say, a monitor) the X server "draws"
*somewhere else* (more on that in a moment), and this information is captured
and delivered to a remotely-connected client.
That is, the whole "screenful" of data is transferred wholesale.
From the client, another stream of information flows back to the server: the data from the client's input devices, such as keyboard keypresses and pointing device movements.

In this paradigm, the whole "graphical session" is run on the server,
is being drawn there, and that ever-changing "screen picture" is being
continuously streamed to the connected client (in a very efficient way).
You may look at this as if the server generates an endless youtube video
which you're streaming and viewing.

As you can see, this paradigm is reversed compared to the original
X network transparency model as the X server runs remotely as well.

You, as a client, typically "see" the whole remote graphical session
in a single window rendered by a specialized piece of software which
you use to create and maintain that remote session.

The upside of this approach is that it makes it easier to carry
non-graphical information through the session—such as sound,
sharing printers and other devices etc.

The final bit of the puzzle is how the data from the remote X server
is delivered to a remotely-connected client.

Basically, there are two ways to achieve that:

- A special piece of software running server-side "hooks" into the
  drawing events generated by the X server and processes them:
  detects which screen regions were updated, and how, combines the
  updates into batches, possibly "downscales" them (lowering the
  color depth and/or resolution) compresses them and sends to the client.

  This is how a VNC server software works.

  The X server might draw on a real hardware device or may draw
  into a special memory area called *the framebuffer.*
  The latter approach allows running any number of graphical sessions for
  remote clients on an otherwise "headless" machine—which has no
  graphical output devices or only rudimentary ones such as text consoles.
- The server uses a special display driver which works like any other
  "real" display driver controlling a hardware device such as a video card,
  but this driver just does what the software described above does—makes
  sure the server's output is efficiently delivered to the client.

To my knowledge, NX/nomachine (and its F/OSS analog, X2Go) implements the
latter approach.

Note that NX/X2Go are not the only solutions using this paradigm.
The popular virtualization stack called KVM supports the SPICE protocol
to connect to the virtualized graphical screen of its guests.
There are Windows drivers implementing the special QXL protocol making
their graphical output be efficiently delivered to the clients using SPICE
(and VNC as well).

Also note, that it's also possible to "export" only a single application
running remotely using this paradigm. I've omitted this possibility in
my explanation to not overwhelm you with information.
For instance, look at [`xpra`](http://xpra.org).

Finally, note that the ongoing "game-changing" technology in the *nix
graphics—the Wayland project—actually supports only this
NX-like approach to working with remote graphical programs.
When it takes over, the "X-way" network transparency will become
a thing of the past. ;-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that was a good high level explanation to connect the random pieces I knew into a system. Am I correct in assuming that https://www.nomachine.com/ works in a similar manner and is just nicely packaged and optimized?

Comment: @LauriK, that would have been too much for a comment, so I've updated my answer; have fun! ;-)